# undefined method `head?' using rabl

Tags: json, padrino, rabl

I am trying to get around this weird error for some time now. This is the basic controller I have:

```
get :index, provides: :json do
  @requests = Request.order(:created_at)
  render 'requests/index'
end

get :show, with: :id, provides: :json do
  @request = Request.find_by(id: params[:id])
  render 'requests/show'
end
```

This is how my rabl json files look like in each case:

index.json.rabl:

```
collection @requests
  attributes :created_at, :updated_at, :user_id, :request_type
```

show.json.rabl:

```
object @request
 attributes :id
```

The first route i.e. :index returns the array of Request objects nicely but the second route i.e :show throws the following error:

```
NoMethodError at /show/1
undefined method `head?' for #<Request:0x007f6814485840>
```

Can someone point at what this error could be about? Why is it looking for head? function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use @request instance variable. Rack stack uses it to store HTTP request there.